# extract only floats from string

Tags: regex, r, xpath

I need to grab only and only floats (these are geocoordinates) from a tag like this

```
   tag = <span id="o_4050267" class="np" style="color:green;cursor:pointer;border-bottom: 1px dotted;" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'goal', 'click', 'map']);init('4050267','37.61909100','55.85712900','37.604843 55.863384','flat2',1,15);">blahblah</span>
```

I tried to use `gsub("[^0-9]+.[^0-9]+", "/", tag)`and then `strsplit()` it picking every time the 4th and 5th element, but of course when scraping 4000+ pages unregularites occur and sometimes there are simply no coordinates for an object, or sometimes there are more and the code picks wrong numbers like the `span's id`, for expample. Moreover, i need to grab only the first pair of the coordinates, the second one is not of my interest.

Or maybe there is a way to work with this tag not as with a string, but to use XPath expressions? Unfortunately, i do not know of a possibility to use xpath to grab info not between tags, but inside themselves.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @Avinash, dataframe with 2 columns of coordinates with a fixed amount of rows (total number of entries on a page), NA's are possible.

Comment: We can't guess irregualrities if you don't give the expected result with more probables cases. The better you enhance your question , the better you have a good answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
\b\d+\.\d+\b
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/pQ9bV3/23

Comment: `>gsub("\b\d+\.\d+\b", "/",geo) 

Error: '\d' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\b\d"`

Comment: @Seva `gsub("\b\d+\.\d+\b", "/",geo,perl=TRUE)`

Comment: I would guess something like `gsub("\\b\\d+\\.\\d+\\b", "/",geo,perl=TRUE)`

Comment: @Seva try David's suggestion